# Javascript clickable multiple times with different results

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm using this code to change the background color of a div when clicking it:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myIdHere").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

...this works fine but I'd like for it to change to another color if I click on it again if possible.

Also I'd like to apply this function to multiple div's. They should all change color when I click on them not depending on each other. Is there a good way to do this or do I have to assign each div a unique Id and create multiple functions? I've tried using the getElementByClass but that did'nt solve my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want each of them to do the same thing independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an object that has everything self contained.
Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/avzoqroa/

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
  click 1
</div>

<div id="second">
  click 2
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var colorSwapper = function(id) {

  this.element = document.getElementById(id);
  this.position = 0;
  this.colors = ["red", "purple", "blue"];

  this.swapColor = function() {
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = this.colors[this.position];
    this.position = (this.position + 1) % this.colors.length;
  }

    //bind event listener for click
  this.element.addEventListener("click", this.swapColor.bind(this));
}

var colorSwapper1 = new colorSwapper("first");
var colorSwapper2 = new colorSwapper("second");
```

Comment: I've seen the demo and it look fine but I'm having trouble to add this to my flex-item's. Is is not supported?

Comment: Another weird thing, it works here: https://jsfiddle.net/cL87haz5/1/ but not on my site it seems.

Comment: No this is a completely different problem. This is because you are looking for an id before the element exists. you need to do 1 of 2 things: wrap it in a window.onload or something like that OR move your script to the bottom of the page right before the closing body tag. The element must have already been loaded before trying to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with name of colors, variable for indexing and end array condition. The index variable *i* should be declared in another script file or outside of function.

```
var colors = {"red", "green", "blue"}; 
if (i == 3)
   i = 0;

document.getElementById("myIdHere").style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
i++;
```

I hope that this solution will be helpful.

Comment: I see. but if I want the same function to multiple independent DIV's do I have to create multiple functions?

Comment: _myFunction_ may take an argument. _myFunction(e)_  and I think that one from properties of this argument is id of element whose fired an event. Something like this document.getElementById(e.target.id).style.backgroundColor = colors[i];